# Creating larger array from row vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a 20 x 2000 array in MATLAB from 20 row vectors which are each 2000 elements long. How would I go about doing this?

Specifically, if my row vectors are of the form `vector_1`, `vector_2`,...`vector_N`, is there an easy way of combining all these row vectors into a larger `N` x 2000 array, possibly using `sprintf`?

Comment: Look up concatenation; http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html?searchHighlight=cat

Comment: `cat(1,array1,array2...)` should do it.

Comment: Thanks! would I be able to loop through arrays in the argument to cat if say i was working with 100 row vectors instead of 20?

Comment: `sprintf` outputs a string.  I don't see how you can create a matrix using this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access programatically to the variables in order to avoid harcoding you may do it like this:

```
vect=[];
for ii=1:N
   vect=eval(strcat('cat(1,vect, vect_',num2str(ii) ,')'));
end
```

This should create strings in the form `cat(1,vect,vect_1)` ,`cat(1,vect,vect_2)`, `cat(1,vect,vect_3)` ... and then evaluate them.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I normally don't vote on answers using `eval`, but I don't see any other choice here... especially with the OP having multiple named vectors.... so +1!

Comment: @rayryeng its definetly  function I avoid to use, but well, sometimes you just need to I guess

Answer (score 1):

If your variables are all named in the style Vector_x and you want to include all variables of this kind, you can use:

```
vectors = who('-regexp','vector_\d+');
A = zeros(length(vectors),numel(eval(vectors{1})));

for i = 1:numel(vectors)
    A(i,:) = eval(vectors{i});
end
```